# Redirect from subfolder and folder to main folder with htaccss

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want a redirect for  links :

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/file.php **to*      http://www.domain.com/file.php  

 http://www.domain.com/folder/folder/file.php **to*           http://www.domain.com/file.php
```

So far I have tried this

```
Redirect 301 /folder/file.php http://www.domain.com/file.php  
Redirect 301 /folder/folder/file.php http://www.domain.com/file.php
```

This is working .I have 100more files like this to redirect , is there an easy way to reduce my code so that I can have less code to redirect more. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)  directive :

Put the following Redirects above other rules in your root/.htaccess file :

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/folder/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 

 RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/([^/]+)/?$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one single rule in your root .htaccess for all these redirects:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ /$1
```